# WPF FileNotFound on startup

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to test my app outside of visual studio (it works inside of it). I select project->publish->path on my computer->from CD or DVD->not online.

I launch the setup and try the app... and nothing happen. I've learned about eventViewer and it shows [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DT9XRPxWgMMHe_p5Rv4JfGyTixHYhIi3b4md2LTgEeU/edit?usp=sharing) and [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R7pp4CD7YPK7diLSfoUa2ki8IL_Dc2UBZ4VMch_ThdM/edit?usp=sharing).

My MainWindow XAML (nothing in the backend) looks like this :

```
<Window x:Class="AHP_Talker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
    TextElement.FontSize="14"
    FontFamily="{materialDesign:MaterialDesignFont}">
<Frame Name="frame" Source="CustomPage/IdentificationPage.xaml" />
</Window>
```

I tried removing the frame and it doesn't change anything

Comment: The links you provided lead to private doc files. I'd need to 'request access' to see them.

Comment: You can use Debug->Other Debug Targets->Debug Installed App Package to see what's going on. Or dnSpy https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy.

Comment: Fixed the files, can't find the program on the debug screen

Comment: The exception you have is `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, probably the MaterialDesign package is missing in your published app.

Comment: If you want to test your app outside of VS, then it's enough to compile in Release and start the app from the command line.